# Exporting a queen bee from Australia to Beirut

Tags: customs-and-immigration, legal, australia, export-certificate, lebanon

I live in Sydney. My cousin who is a hobbyist bee keeper asked me to get him an Australian queen bee. I know that Australian laws are very strict on what to get into the country but how about exporting living object such a a queen bee? What is the procedure in this case?

Edit: I am travelling myself, and I want to take a queen bee with me? Would it be possible to carry it with me or perhaps the airline could handle this as they would normally handle a pet? The usual route is Sydney-Dubai-Beirut.

Comment: I'd be much more concerned about the procedure to import the bee into another country. Where is the bee going?

Comment: @ZachLipton To Beirut, Lebanon

Comment: Australia exports lots of bees, so this seems pretty straightforward on that end. It's the import end where you might have trouble, and I can't find any information in English.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I am googling this but I can't find straightforward info. I want to know what is the procedure to export a queen bee, I also need info on how to handle that, especially on a 24+ hrs flight. Regarding the import laws at the final destination I will leave that for my cousin to figure out.

Comment: If I were you, I would let the apiary handle export. Search for something like "package bee exporter in australia" to start.

Comment: If you're personally bringing him the bee in Lebanon, I'd recommend against leaving that for your cousin to figure it out. You'll be the one in trouble with the Lebanese authorities for violating agricultural rules if you don't follow any required procedures. There may be formalities you'll have to deal with in any stopover countries on your way there as well.

Comment: I dunno...from what little research I've done, this does _not_ appear to be something you'll put in checked baggage, at least not legally; as far as I can tell it has to be specially packed and ship by air cargo. You don't want to wind up with Bees on a Plane...

Comment: Have you tried asking the [Lebanese Embassy](http://lebanon.embassy.gov.au/)?

Comment: You could put a few of them in a small zipped wallet. Keep it in your trousers pocket throughout. It shouldn't trigger the metal gate. If found out  somehow act surprised or claim you only eat live food.

Comment: @mega_creamery that resonates my mind!

Comment: I'm a bit concerned about the idea of smuggling the bee. There are many serious problems due to diseases that have been spread around the world by air travel. If there is a rule against importing an Australian bee into Lebanon, there may also be a good reason for it. Do your research, and do it carefully.

Comment: Exactly. There are reasons why the movement of bees around the world is controlled, and failure to follow the proper procedures (as an example, [the rules](https://www.aphis.usda.gov/regulations/vs/iregs/animals/downloads/ca_hb_us_pc.pdf) for bringing queen bees into Canada from the US, including DNA tests) could do serious harm (not to mention that the consequences for smuggling agricultural items are usually quite unpleasant). Bees in a zipped wallet stuffed in your pants doesn't sound like a proper way to transport bees either.

Comment: I was being sarcastic...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The New South Wales Government in 2007 [endorsed](http://www.dpi.nsw.gov.au/archive/agriculture-today-stories/ag-today-archives/february-2007/live-bee-exports) the following bee export experts: Dr Doug Somerville, (02) 4828 6619, Goulburn, Nick Annand, Bathurst, (02) 6330 1210.

Comment: Care to elaborate a bit? Who are they? Why these guys? What do they do?

Comment: @JoErNanO I had the same questions that's why I have added the link. This is legit advice, not spam despite how it looks, these people are bee export experts endorsed by the New South Wales Government. I have rewritten the answer.